# .htaccess spaces in name

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am working on a project that uses `.htaccess` for redirecting `www.example.com/Name` to a profile page. I have it working fine on single word names. The issue is that if the name is "San Francisco" I get a 404 no matter what I try. Below is the line in my `.htaccess`.

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ viewProfile.php?Name=$1 [L]
```

I am wondering if there is something that I can do so if I give the URL `www.example.com/San_Francisco` or something like that it would work. I read around some other questions that had to do with a similar topic but never got to a working solution.

(seems like `www.example.com/San%20Francisco` would be best because when I link that of course is what fills the URL space)

Comment: A `+` could also go in place of a space and should still arrive at the same place.

Comment: @AuntJamaima A `+` (plus) in the URL-path part of the URL is a literal `+`, not a space. The `+` is only an alternative encoding for the space in the query string part of the URL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ viewProfile.php?Name=$1 [L]
> ```

Your `RewriteRule` *pattern* does not include a *space*, so it will never match a space in the requested URL, eg. `wwww.example.com/San%20Francisco` (`%20` being a URL encoded space).

Note that although the space is URL encoded (%-encoded) in the request (in order to make valid request), the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the %-decoded URL-path, ie. a literal space. A literal space must be backslash escaped in the regex (because spaces are delimiters in Apache config files). For example:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\ ]+)$ viewProfile.php?Name=$1 [L]
```

Alternatively, you can use the short-hand character class `\s` for any white-space character. Some would consider this easier to read (since you can't actually "see" spaces):

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\s]+)$ viewProfile.php?Name=$1 [L]
```

Or, you can just use a non-escaped space and surround the entire pattern in double quotes:

```
RewriteRule "^([A-Za-z0-9 ]+)$" viewProfile.php?Name=$1 [L]
```

Note that the above patterns allow spaces at the start and end of the URL-path (profile name). These are obviously best avoided when the profile name is created in the first place.

Needless to say, *spaces* are problematic in URLs and best avoided from the start. In the case of a "profile name", you would ideally create a separate "URL version" of the profile name that is used only in the URL, eg. all lowercase, convert spaces to hyphens: `/san-francisco`

---

To include hyphens (`-`) in the pattern, these must be included at the start or end of the character class (since hyphens otherwise carry special meaning in a character class). For example:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\s-]+)$ viewProfile.php?Name=$1 [L]
```

---

To allow underscores (`_`) as well in the profile name (URL-path) then simply add the `_` anywhere in the character class:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_\s-]+)$ viewProfile.php?Name=$1 [L]
```

Which is the same as:

```
RewriteRule ^([\w\s-]+)$ viewProfile.php?Name=$1 [L]
```

Using the short-hand character class `\w` to represent any word character ie. `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

---

**UPDATE:**

If you are getting a 403 Forbidden response with the above rule when *spaces* are present in the requested URL-path then you will need to add the `B` flag to explicitly escape the backreference before it is applied to the *substitution* string.

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^([\w\s-]+)$ viewProfile.php?Name=$1 [B,L]
```

This is the result of a recent "security" update to Apache that now rejects unencoded special characters in the query string (in the past they were implicitly encoded - so not an issue). See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75685188/369434) to the following question for more information: [AH10411 error: Managing spaces and %20 in apache mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75684314/ah10411-error-managing-spaces-and-20-in-apache-mod-rewrite)

Comment: Any reason why any of these solutions wouldn't be working for me? I'm using this solution to handle a /app/search/query%20goes%20here type scenario. I keep getting 403's.

Comment: @ScottRichardson My hosting is also giving me 403, did you find out?

Comment: @ScottRichardson I've updated my answer to address the 403 issue. This is the result of a recent Apache "security" update.

Comment: @MartinZvarík I've updated my answer to address the 403 issue. This is the result of a recent Apache "security" update.