# AH10411 error: Spaces and %20 result in 403 Forbidden with Apache mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have updated Apache today (to 2.4.56-1) and a load of `.htaccess` rewrites that used to work are now getting AH10411 errors, relating to spaces in the query. I'm struggling for a 'proper' solution.

The user clicks on a link such as `<a href='FISH%20J12345.6-78919'>clickme</a>` - as you can see the space in the link URL has been encoded as `%20`.

The `.htaccess` file in the relevant server directory contains and executes this relevant directive:

```
RewriteRule ^(FISH\s*J[0-9\.]+-?\+?[0-9]+)$ myPage.php?sourceName=$1 [L,QSA]
```

(In the above I am checking for spaces, not `%20`, as the browser seems to be converting it to space before it makes it to this rule).

This was working until I updated Apache; now users get a 403 error, and my Apache error log reports:

> AH10411: Rewritten query string contains control characters or spaces

This appears to be a new error, because Googling it finds nothing!

Editing my pages to (for example) change the space to an underscore and handle it correctly is not really an option, as the design is intended to support users being able to enter a URL directly using the name of the object they care about. So far, the only workaround I've found is a bit ugly, namely capturing the two parts of the source name separately in the regexp, thus:

```
RewriteRule ^(FISH)\s*(J[0-9\.]+-?\+?[0-9]+)$ myPage.php?sourceName=$1+$2 [L,QSA]
                  ^   ^                                               ^^^
```

(I tried `$1%20$2` at the end, which also resulted in the same error.)

Is there a better solution for this? i.e. how am I "supposed" to handle the case of spaces in a URL, when it's in a string I want to capture and pass as an argument to the underlying page?

Comment: "I tried $1%20$2 at the end, which also went badly" - this produced the same error I assume?

Comment: Same here, our whole website is broken because of this issue

Comment: @MrWhite yes - $1%20$2 gives exactly the same error.

Comment: @Lucas What version of Apache are you using?

Comment: I had exactly the same problem on the localhost, on the version being developed. Hosting is fine. A couple of days ago everything was working fine, and then all of a sudden such an ass :( Google and YOU helped me.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

> (I tried $1%20$2 at the end, which also went badly).

This looks like a bug. Encoding the *space* as `%20` in the query string should be valid. You can also encode the *space* as `+` in the query string (as in your workaround).

In your original rule, Apache should be encoding the space (as `%20`) when making the internal rewrite (since a literal space is not valid in the URL). However, it would seem Apache is then baulking at the encoded space (or not auto-encoding the URL in the rewrite)?!

You can try using the `B` flag in your original rule. The `B` flag tells mod_rewrite to URL-encode the backreference before applying this to the *substitution* string. However, this would seem to be dependent on Apache encoding the space as `+` in the query string (as opposed to `%20` which it would ordinarily do). Certainly in earlier versions of Apache, this would only have resulted in Apache encoding the *space* as `%20` (not `+`), however, since version 2.4.26 Apache has introduced a new flag `BNP` (`backrefnoplus`) which explicitly informs Apache *not* to use a `+`, so you would think that by default, it would use a `+`. (Unfortunately I can't just test this myself at the moment.)

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^(FISH\s*J[\d.]+-?\+?\d+)$ myPage.php?sourceName=$1 [B,QSA,L]
```

(Minor point... no need to backslash-escape the literal dot when used inside a regex character class. I also reduced the digit ranges to the shorthand `\d`.)

*Aside:* Can you have both `-` and `+` at the same time before the last set of digits (denoted by the subpattern `-?\+?`)? It looks like it should perhaps be one or the other (or nothing at all)? eg. `[-+]?`.

> Is there a better solution for this? i.e. how am I "supposed" to handle the case of spaces in a URL, when it's in a string I want to capture and pass as an argument to the underlying page?

Not really (although your solution is not strictly correct - see below). In your particular example, that only contains *spaces* you shouldn't *need* to do anything, as mod_rewrite should automatically URL-encode any URL that is not valid. (There is an `NE` - `noescape` - flag to explicitly prevent mod_rewrite from doing this - which is sometimes necessary to prevent already encoded characters being doubly encoded.) You can always use the `B` flag in URL-rewrites of this form (as mentioned above). You would *need* to use the `B` flag if there were other special characters, such as `&` (a special character in the query string) which would not otherwise be URL-encoded (effectively resulting in the URL parameter value being truncated).

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(FISH)\s*(J[0-9\.]+-?\+?[0-9]+)$ myPage.php?sourceName=$1+$2 [L,QSA]
> ```

An issue with your solution is that you are allowing 0 (ie. "none") or more *spaces* in the request and enforcing a single *space* in the resulting URL parameter. This is not the same as your original directive, that would preserve the spaces (or lack of) from the original request.

Could there be 0 or more spaces in the initial request?

If yes, and these need to be preserved then it may just be easier to repeat this rule for as many "spaces" as you need. You could implement a search/replace, but that may be overkill.

> (In the above I am checking for spaces, not %20, as the browser seems to be converting it to space before it makes it to this rule).

The URL-path that the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against is first URL-decoded (%-decoded), which is why you need to match against a literal *space* and not `%20`. This has nothing to do with the "browser". Any literal *spaces* in the URL-path "must" be URL-encoded as `%20` in the HTTP request that leaves the browser/user-agent otherwise it's simply not valid.

---

#### (UPDATE) Restrict which non-alphanumeric characters are encoded

There was a comment (since *deleted*) where the user was also passing a `+` (literal plus) in the URL-path and seemingly expecting this to be passed as-is to the query string (via an internal rewrite) which would then be seen as an encoded *space*. However, the use of the `B` flag (as above) would result in the literal `+` being URL encoded as `%2b` thus preserving the literal `+` - which would ordinarily be the correct behaviour. However, if the `+` should be copied as-is and thus seen as an encoded *space* (not a literal `+`) in the resulting query string then you can restrict the non-alphanumeric characters that the `B` flag will encode (requires Apache 2.4.26+). ie. Exclude the `+`.

For instance, you could limit the encoding to *spaces* and `?` only. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?query=$1 "[B= ?,L]"
```

`+` will no longer be encoded in the backreference, so its special meaning in the query string (as an encoded *space*) will still apply.

NB: You can't encode only *spaces* (since a space cannot be used as the last character in the `B` flag value argument), hence the additional `?` character. Consequently, the flags argument needs to be surrounded in double quotes, since *spaces* are otherwise argument delimiters.

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b
- [Mod rewrite. B flag doesn't work with spaces. AH10411: Rewritten query string contains control characters or spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75928324/mod-rewrite-b-flag-doesnt-work-with-spaces-ah10411-rewritten-query-string-co)

Comment: Adding the B flag was enough in the case of my server to solve this issue, which does indeed only appear to have emerged through a bug in the latest Apache:
Server version: Apache/2.4.56 (cPanel)
Server built:   Mar  8 2023 15:06:38

Comment: Thanks! Adding the B flag has fixed this for me. On your other points: I can't remember why I didn't use \d; I suspect I copied an old rule that only allowed 0-5 at one point... As to spaces: the "correct" ID will always have one space, but I am deliberately allowing users to enter a URL with/out it. So your criticism of my current solution is completely valid, but in this specific case, it doesn't matter. And the +/- issue: I require exactly one + or - sign (but not both) so you are right just [+-] would be better. I was obviously half asleep when building the original rexep!

Comment: I would like to thank @MrWhite for their explanation. Adding the B flag also solved this issue for me for my Ajax-powered search feature. Thank you :)

Comment: We had a similar issue in our recently patched RHEL 8 systems, which updated Apache to 2.4.37-51. This: 
`RewriteRule ^foo/bar/(.*)$ https://example.com/ab?cd=search&ef=1&q=$1 [L]`
stopped working when $1 had spaces in it, I think encoded as %20. Our sites, which use CloudFront would give a CloudFront error when the above rewrite triggered. 
Using this instead: 
`RewriteRule ^foo/bar/(.*)$ https://example.com/ab?cd=search&ef=1&q=$1 [B,L,NE]` 
looks to resolve it. No more CloudFront error and the redirect works, encoding the spaces as + or %2b. Thank you @MrWhite!

Comment: @SpecialMonkey "encoding the spaces as + or %2b" - `%2b` is a literal `+` (plus), not a _space_. When encoding the _space_ in the query string part of the URL it would need to be either `+` or `%20`. The URL-path that the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ matches against has already been URL decoded - which is the problem since it captures a _literal space_, not an encoded space.

Comment: @MrWhite Thanks for the clarification. To my knowledge, this type of rewrite broke after a RHEL 8 patch to Apache; I believe related to CVE-2023-25690. The `[B,L,NE]` flag set seems to fix. The `[L]` only flag I think caused a 403. Some other combination that didn't turn spaces into plusses in the query, maybe `[B,L]`, caused the target redirect to fail. It landed on the target system but the query didn't produce the desired result. The target system I think expected %20 for spaces in the query but also worked with plusses.

Answer (score 16):

It's a recent [security fix](https://github.com/apache/httpd/commit/d78a166fedd9d02c23e4b71d5f53bd9b2c4b9a51).

```
apache2 (2.4.52-1ubuntu4.4) jammy-security; urgency=medium

  * SECURITY UPDATE: HTTP request splitting with mod_rewrite and mod_proxy
    - debian/patches/CVE-2023-25690-1.patch: don't forward invalid query
      strings in modules/http2/mod_proxy_http2.c,
      modules/mappers/mod_rewrite.c, modules/proxy/mod_proxy_ajp.c,
      modules/proxy/mod_proxy_balancer.c, modules/proxy/mod_proxy_http.c,
      modules/proxy/mod_proxy_wstunnel.c.
    - debian/patches/CVE-2023-25690-2.patch: Fix missing APLOGNO in
      modules/http2/mod_proxy_http2.c.
    - CVE-2023-25690
  * SECURITY UPDATE: mod_proxy_uwsgi HTTP response splitting
    - debian/patches/CVE-2023-27522.patch: stricter backend HTTP response
      parsing/validation in modules/proxy/mod_proxy_uwsgi.c.
    - CVE-2023-27522

 -- Marc Deslauriers <marc.deslauriers@ubuntu.com>  Wed, 08 Mar 2023 12:32:01 -0500
```

Comment: I still have this problem (and need the B flag fix) after updating apache to Apache/2.4.56 (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS)
Server built:   2023-03-09T07:33:59  I guess this ubuntu version didn't get the Apache2 security update patch?

Comment: @user6096790 the B flag fix is what you need when the server did get the fix.

Answer (score 1):

Debugging Apache (ErrorLog with LogLevel rewrite:trace6) shows, that calling

```
/FISH%20J12345.6-78919
```

with

```
RewriteRule ^(FISH\s*J[0-9\.]+-?\+?[0-9]+)$ myPage.php?sourceName=$1 [L,QSA]
```

decodes the %20 correctly to Space before mod_rewrite gets it. And the URL is rewritten to

```
'myPage.php?sourceName=FISH J12345.6-78919'
```

There is a Space in the query param and mod_rewrite does not like this (anymore).

Actually two things happen with mod_rewrite and a rule like

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

First the PATH part of the URL is decoded (beware that a + in the PATH part is a +, and not decoded to a Space) and handed to mod_rewrite. This then is put to $1. The QUERY part of the original URL is not decoded, but merged into the rewritten PATH part. Then that new URL is handed back to Apache. The php then decodes the QUERY params. Which makes for a double decoding of the PATH part, as in the rewritten URL it is a QUERY param.

Without [B], e.g. `/A%2520B/?a=b%2520c` (%25 decoded is %) is rewritten to `q=A%20B/&a=b%2520c` ending up in php as `"q" => "A B/", "a" => "b%20c"`. Actually not quite what is expected at first sight (at least what I expected up to now, which was `"q" => "A%20B/"`).

So probably using [B] for moving PATH parts to QUERY param is the better choice anyway, ensuring it only gets decoded once.

With [B], `/A%2520B/?a=b%2520c` is finally rewritten to `q=A%2520B%2f&a=b%2520c` ending up in php as `"q" => "A%20B/", "a" => "b%20c"`. Looks better to me.

With [B] the FISH link gets encoded like so `escaping backreference 'FISH J12345.6-78919' to 'FISH+J12345%2e6%2d78919'`, so encoding the Space is done with the + (not %20). In php it gets decoded again.

I suppose, for single encoded PATH parts, not using [B] in most cases was ok, most likely because the % sign is not much used in PATH parts. Using [B] for me is now the better solution.

There is one caveat, answered already elsewhere here: As + is valid in the PATH part, `/A+%2bB/` is passed to mod_rewrite as `A++B/` (so the first + stays a +), finally being passed as `q=A%2b%2bB%2f` ending up in php as `"q" => "A++B/"`. This cannot be overcome, as + is handled different in PATH part than in QUERY part.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, after `RewriteEngine on`

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.*)\ (.*)$ /$1+$2 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: This isn't a "solution", this is an inefficient workaround at best. You should change the URLs in the underlying application (the URLs you are actually linking to). (Without changing the URLs, it is preferable to use the `B` flag as mentioned in the other answers, to correctly encode the _space_ in the _substitution_ string.)