# .htaccess rewrite space in URL returns 403 Forbidden error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have PHP application, on Ubuntu Apache web server.

Application have search feature, as GET type of request.

After submitting search string, Apache returns 403 Forbidden error, if I have more that one word as a search string, like:

`https://my-url.com/publications/index/search:nikola%20tesla/submit:Submit`

But it works fine, if I have only one word as search string, like:

`https://my-url.com/publications/index/search:nikola/submit:Submit`

I checked Apache log files, and it logs next error in this case:

AH10411: Rewritten query string contains control character or spaces

File /app/.htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
```

File /app/webroot/.htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Can you help me to solve this? Tried to fix it with directives in .htaccess but no luck.

Comment: We cannot help you, unless you share your .htaccess file, so we check what the rules are there... [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: How is this URL being built? A `:` shouldn't be a delimiter for a GET request. The `:` is a control character in a URL.

Comment: Does this answer your Q: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75684314/ah10411-error-managing-spaces-and-20-in-apache-mod-rewrite

Comment: I have just shared my .htaccess file, as update of a question.

Comment: _"Rewritten query string contains control character or spaces"_ - Have you tried the `B` flag? https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b

Comment: The B flag actually worked in my case! Thanks @CBroe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AH10411 error: Managing spaces and %20 in apache mod\_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75684314/ah10411-error-managing-spaces-and-20-in-apache-mod-rewrite)