# Mod rewrite. B flag doesn't work with spaces. AH10411: Rewritten query string contains control characters or spaces

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

After apache update, my server started dropping this error in URL queries, containing spaces:

> AH10411: Rewritten query string contains control characters or spaces

URL looks as follows:

`www.example.com/modulename/searchfuncname/filter,searchstring,quick fox jumps/`

`.htaccess` as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?QueryString=%{REQUEST_URI} [B,L]
</IfModule>
```

I tried adding `B` flag, removing `B` flag, adding `BNP` flag and combinations of both or none.

Nothing helped. With any URL provided, server drops the very same error.

When I try to manually replace spaces with `%20`:
`www.example.com/modulename/searchfuncname/filter,searchstring,quick%20fox%20jumps/`
server replaces them back, gives 403 responce and drops AH10411 error.

But for some reason, if I replace space with `+` sign, server works. Disregarding `BPN` flag.

I tried all the variants, described in this thread:
[AH10411 error: Managing spaces and %20 in apache mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75684314/ah10411-error-managing-spaces-and-20-in-apache-mod-rewrite)
none worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?QueryString=%{REQUEST_URI} [B,L]
> ```

The `B` flag doesn't work here because you are not using a *backreference* (you are using the `REQUEST_URI` server variable instead). Try the following instead:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?QueryString=/$1 [B,L]
```

> When I try to manually replace spaces with "%20": `/modulename/searchfuncname/filter,searchstring,quick%20fox%20jumps/` server replaces them back

This would make no difference, because this is identical to the first request. If you don't explicitly URL-encode the *spaces* in the initial request, the browser does this for you (when it makes the request) - in order to make a valid URL. (Look at the network traffic in the browser - you will see `%20` regardless of whether you have manually encoded the space or not).

But yes, the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches the URL-decoded URL-path anyway.

> But for some reason, if I replace space with "+" sign, server works. Disregarding BPN flag.

`%20` is a URL-encoded *space*, regardless of where it is used in the URL. However, a `+` in the URL-path is a literal `+` (plus). But, a `+` in the query string is a URL-encoded *space* (alternative encoding). So, yes, if you used `+` in the URL-path of the original request then it "bypasses" this problem. The **`BNP`** flag does not apply, since it is not encoding a *space*, it is simply copying a literal `+`.

---

#### UPDATE: Limit what is encoded

> `$_GET` now doesn't break into array if URL is provided with addditional parameters like `/fox/&tail=red`

Probably because the `&` is being URL-encoded in the resulting query string. You can limit the encoding to *spaces* and `?` only (requires Apache 2.4.26+). For example:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?QueryString=/$1 "[B= ?,L]"
```

`&` will no longer be encoded in the backreference, so its special meaning in the query string will still apply.

NB: You can't encode only *spaces* (since *spaces* can't be used as the last character), hence the additional `?` character. Consequently, the *flags* argument needs to be surrounded in double quotes.

Comment: this solution helps. kinda. unfortunately it also breaks the other functions. $_GET now doesn't break into array if URL is provided with addditional parameters like /fox/&tail=red

Comment: @YaroslavUstinovsky You can limit the encoding to prevent `&` being URL-encoded in the resulting query string. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks! "[B= ?,L]" this last part did the trick. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same and due to circumstances I found the easy way:

```
#
# php-fpm can use .user.ini instead of .htaccess
#
<Files ".user.ini">
    Require all denied
</Files>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteOptions AllowAnyURI
    #
    # Authorization header for JWT backend
    #
    SetEnvIf Authorization .+ HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$0

    #
    # Don't rewrite if dir/link/file exists
    #
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule .* - [L]

    #
    # Handle in route class...
    #
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule .* - [E=REQUEST_SCHEME:http]

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
    RewriteRule .* - [E=REQUEST_SCHEME:https]

    RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /index.php?request=- [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

basically it is this setting:     RewriteOptions AllowAnyURI