# Rewriting URL with two parameters which contains spaces results in a 403 Forbidden

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**I have a PHP file:**

```
example.com/products/index.php
```

**My goal is to able to do this:**

```
example.com/products/186/Hello to you
```

and in PHP I can do `$_GET['id']` which will be `186`,

and `$_GET['cat']` which will be "Hello to you".

**So far I tried this below, but I get:**

> You don't have permission to access this resource.
> Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

# HTTP to HTTPS canonical redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Abort early if the request already maps to (or looks like) a file or directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.\w{2,4}$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(products)/([^/]*)/?(.*) $1/index.php?id=$2&cat=$3 [L]

# 3. Extensionless URLs for other requests  (this below works fine and is for something else)
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

Comment: **Nobody** does it this way. With regular rewrite you always have $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], and you can split it using explode(). This is WAY more flexible as it allows any URL format. Don't meddle with .htaccess. Keep it a simple rewrite to index.php and parse all requests in PHP

Comment: @YourCommonSense I heard using server request URI is very unreliable :/

Comment: Whatever you heard it's 100% wrong.

Comment: After all, in your .htaccess you are using the same REQUEST_URI. If it's "unreliable", then your .htaccess would be unreliable too

Comment: @YourCommonSense The problem is if I "mywebsite.com/products/186/Hello to you",  it's not going to use the index.php that's in the PRODUCTS folder.
there's only so much I can do in PHP.   do you know what I mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "403 Forbidden" problem is related to a recent update to Apache and the *spaces* in your requested URL. As discussed in the following question:

- [AH10411 error: Managing spaces and %20 in apache mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75684314/ah10411-error-managing-spaces-and-20-in-apache-mod-rewrite)

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(products)/([^/]*)/?(.*) $1/index.php?id=$2&cat=$3 [L]
> ```

Since you are permitting *spaces* in the requested URL (encoded as `%20` in the request), which you are *capturing* and passing to the *substitution* string, you need to include the `B` flag in order to URL encode the backreferences.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteRule ^(products)/([^/]*)/?(.*) $1/index.php?id=$2&cat=$3 [B,L]
```

However, your regex (`RewriteRule` *pattern* / 1st argument) would seem too "flexible" as it makes the 3rd path segment optional (ie. a URL of the form `/products/anything` would be accepted) - is that intentional?

To match only URLs of the form `/products/<id>/<cat>` (where `<id>` consists only of the digits 0-9) then your `RewriteRule` *pattern* should be modified to something like the following instead:

```
^(products)/(\d+)/(.+)
```

---

It's mentioned in comments about using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` instead of passing the URL parameters. This is OK, but doesn't save much (if anything) in this instance as this looks like an isolated case and not how the rest of your site is constructed. In this case your rule in `.htaccess` would become:

```
RewriteRule ^(products)/\d+/. $1/index.php [L]
```

(*Aside:* Although an added benefit of this approach is that it does naturally prevent the same resource being accessible via a URL of the form `index.php?id=<id>&cat=<cat>`, thus avoiding a potential *duplicate content* issue. An additional rule can be used in `.htaccess` to redirect such requests to the canonical URL.)

And in PHP you parse the values directly from the requested URL-path (as stored in the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` superglobal). For example:

```
<?php
$urlPath = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],PHP_URL_PATH);
$urlPathParts = explode('/',$urlPath);
$id ??= $urlPathParts[1];
$cat ??= $urlPathParts[2];
```

Comment: Mr white, as always, you're a genius!

Comment: one question though, when I use code above and go to:  products/186 232. I get 404. Because there's a space between 186 and 232. Is this supposed to happen? :/

Comment: @Matilda So, `186 232` (with a _space_) is the "id"?! And no "cat" parameter? In that case you would need to revert back to using something like your original regex as the `RewriteRule` _pattern_. ie. `^(products)/([^/]*)/?(.*)`. (Which would then rewrite the request to `products/index.php?id=186+232&cat=`.)