# Access URL/filename having space | Apache | htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

### Root Folder Structure

[image]

**Root .htaccess**

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .py

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [BCTLS]

php_value file_uploads 1
php_value memory_limit 1024M
php_value post_max_size 1024M
php_value upload_max_filesize 1024M
```

### Inside "public" folder

[image]

.htaccess in public folder

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/robots.txt
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?q=$1 [QSA,L]
```

### My Problem

I cannot access the file `p 1.jpg` like:

```
http://example.local/p%201.jpg
```

but it works if I change as follows

```
http://example.local/public/p%201.jpg
```

Also if a `p.jpg` is there, I can access
`http://example.local/p.jpg` - without any issue.

Comment: Change `BCTLS` with just ``L`

Comment: "I cannot access the file...." - What response are you getting?

Comment: Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.

Comment: From your example, presumably `/public/p 1.jpg` (with a _space_) exists as a physical file? What version of Apache you are using? With your 2nd rewrite (in the `public` folder), what is the actual file that handles the request?

Comment: Your "file structure" also seemingly shows only `p 1`, not `p 1.jpg`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comments...

> I can access my MVC PHP application with the URL `example.local/ws/getPost/mmm` but NOT with as follows `example.local/ws/getPost/mm%20m` Even if BOTH URLs are VALID the second ONE shows Forbidden

This is a different issue to the one you posted as an example in your question. In your question, `p 1.jpg` (presumably) ends up mapping directly to a physical file after the first rewrite (ie. `/public/p 1.jpg`).

However, in this second example the URL is further rewritten by the rule (below) in the `/public/.htaccess` file, since it does not map to a physical file:

> ```
> :
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?q=$1 [QSA,L]
> ```

Try adding the `B` flag (or *perhaps* `BCTLS` if on Apache 2.4.57+) to re-encode the *space* in the backreference (captured URL-path) when passed to the query string. (The URL-path that the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against is URL-decoded.)

You should also be rewriting directly to the file that handles the request (eg. `index.php`?). Currently you are relying on the `DirectoryIndex` (which requires an additional subrequest), and which has not been explicitly defined here, so it is not clear to other devs what the intention is.

For example:

```
:
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?q=$1 [B,QSA,L]
```

(I initially *assumed* `index.py` because of the `AddHandler` directive in the parent `.htaccess` file, but from your later comment it would seem this is a "PHP application".)

Further reference:

- [AH10411 error: Managing spaces and %20 in apache mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75684314/ah10411-error-managing-spaces-and-20-in-apache-mod-rewrite)

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be problem:

```bash
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [BCTLS]
```

[Due to presence of `BCTLS` flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_bctls) that only escapes control characters and the space character.

It appears from your examples that you want to handle all the URLs as you receive from client hence you can just use:

```bash
RewriteRule .* public/$0 [L]
```

Comment: It works for the example. But unfortunately it does not works for my whole work like as follows:

I can access my MVC PHP application with the URL
http://example.local/ws/getPost/mmm

but NOT with as follows
http://example.local/ws/getPost/mm%20m

Even if BOTH URLs are VALID the second ONE shows 

Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.

Comment: @RethNath That would seem to be a different issue than the example you posted in the question. Since `/public/ws/getPost/mm m` does not map to a physical file it then invokes the rule in the second `/public/.htaccess` file that further rewrites the request to your "MVC PHP application". You may need to add the `B` flag to this second rule, as mentioned in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76239790/369434).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all guys

I solved my whole issue by correcting the htaccess in the public folder as follows

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?q=$1 [BCTLS,L]
```

Using Apache 2.4.57

Comment: This is the same as what I suggested (and explained) in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76239790/369434). However, the `B` flag is likely preferable here. (And you should be rewriting directly to the file that handles the request.) But both the suggestion in @anubhava's answer and this are presumably required to resolve this issue? Please consider upvoting (and accepting) answers you find helpful. Thanks, much appreciated :)