# What is the correct regex for converting a blog link to a php file in .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a PHP based website that I am trying to adapt to processing SEO friendly URLs for blogs, stories, etc.  I am trying to get `.htaccess` working so that it can convert:

```
example.com/blog/b-this-is-a-post
```

to:

```
example.com/blog.php?id=b-this-is-a-post
```

I am getting 404 page errors using the following `.htaccess` rules.  I was getting 500 Internal server errors until I created the noted `.htaccess` rules.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ blog.php?id=$1 [NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

The redirect to HTTPS works fine, but the regex line to convert the blog link to the `blog.php` file to process it isn't working.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.com [NC]
> RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
> RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ blog.php?id=$1 [NC,QSA]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
> ```

You seem to have *mashed* two different rules (HTTP to HTTPS *and* your blog rewrite) together and broken both. The "redirect to HTTPS" cannot work "fine", since it is processed unconditionally and would create a redirect loop (unless HTTPS requests are not processing this `.htaccess` file?!).

`RewriteCond` (conditions) are only applied to the first `RewriteRule` directive that follows. Together, the `RewriteRule` directive and preceding *conditions* form a single rule.

Otherwise, your regex is "OK" (except that it is arguably matching too much).

You need to reorder your directives like this:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (^|\.)example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ blog.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Unless you are serving multiple domains then you can remove the initial *condition* that checks the `HTTP_HOST`.

MultiViews needs to also be disabled (it may already be), otherwise the `blog` to `blog.php` will be missing the `id` URL parameter.

I've removed the `NC` flag on the *blog* rewrite. Ideally, the regex should be more restrictive and only match valid `id` *values*, rather than *everything*. Certain [special characters will result in an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75684314/ah10411-error-managing-spaces-and-20-in-apache-mod-rewrite) with this rule.

Once this is fully tested, the HTTP to HTTPS redirect should be a 301 (permanent) redirect, not a 302 (temporary) redirect as you have currently.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.  I tried this and still get 404 page not found errors.  I did modify the regex to tighten up the search criteria using ^blog/([a-z0-9-]+)$ which still didn't work.

Comment: @karlk123 I'm wondering if your `.htaccess` file is doing anything at all - are `.htaccess` overrides enabled? With the `.htaccess` file you posted in your question, you said the "redirect to HTTPS works fine", however, what you posted should have resulted in a redirect loop (as I mentioned above) - there's no way that could have worked "fine" (if it was doing anything at all).

Comment: The .htaccess file is doing something as it forces https.  Now I understand the logic flow better.  With an https url, the rewrite rules don't get processed.  If I put the blog rewrite rule before the https redirect, I get the message The page isn’t redirecting properly.  So the .httaccess file is being processed.  A question, if the url is http, then the rewrite rule forcing https has the L flag, so I think things stop, right?

Comment: Here is an update. Some progress. When I have this as the last line `^(.*)/blog/([a-z0-9-]+)$ $1/blog.php?id=$2 [QSA]` in `.htaccess`, I get the appropriate thing displayed except all of my relative links point to the `blog` directory so css, images, etc aren't displayed properly. If I use this line instead `RewriteRule ^/blog/([a-z0-9-]+)$ /blog.php?id=$1 [QSA]`, I get 404 errors. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Ok, I am realizing that my relative links are because the original URL had `blog` as the last directory.  Is there a way to force php to use the rewritten URL, not the original URL?  Is there something in `.htacess` for this? If not I will have to update my links to be direct, not relative.