# Apache / .htaccess issue when spaces in folder or file names

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a site where users can upload files. Historically no sanitising of the file names or folders was done. This was not a problem whilst the files were located in public_html/uploads but since moving them outside the public_html folder for security reasons and using PHP to retrieve the requested files, any path or filename containing a space throws the following error:

> 403 Forbidden - You don't have permission to access this resource.

In the `filehandler.php` file that I've created to fetch the requested files I've tried `preg_replace()` to change *spaces* into `%20` and I've tried `urlencode()` and `rawurlencode()` on the requested file but I still get the same error.

After a time it became clear that the problem wasn't in the `filehandler.php` but probably to do with the Apache configuration, particularly the `.htaccess` file I created to point the user file request to `filehandler.php` - the request is dying before `filehandler.php` is even reached. Here is my `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^uploads/(.+)$ filehandler.php?file=$1 [QSA]
```

I found the above `.htaccess` code from elsewhere on this site and it works fine if no spaces are encountered but I have little experience with `.htaccess` syntax and workings so I'm not sure if it's possible to add another rule or modify that one to allow for spaces.

I've spent many hours now reading similar questions and answers but none quite matching my particular problem.

As a last resort I could rename all the files and folders to replace the spaces with underscores but I'd also have to do the same on the SQL table containing all the links so am hoping not to have to.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to add the `B` flag to that rule to URL encode the captured backreference before it is applied to the _substitution_ string. See the linked ["duplicate" question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75684314/ah10411-error-spaces-and-20-result-in-403-forbidden-with-apache-mod-rewrite) for details. (_Aside:_ Your rule should also include the `L` (or `END`) flag, to prevent further rules being processed.)

Comment: Thanks for your comment and linking to the previously asked question. But adding B still doesn't work for me although at least I don't get any errors now. I've put a detailed breakdown as a response in the other thread if you're able to offer any further help it would be appreciated.

Comment: "But adding B still doesn't work for me although at least I don't get any errors now." - That resolves the question you are asking here. If it still doesn't work then that is likely something else entirely and you should ask another question.